# PHP Session file permission denied

Tags: php, linux, session, permissions, chmod

session start returns an error related to file permission.
Chmod doesn't affect.
Is there another way to fix the warning ?

> Warning: session_start(): open(/var/lib/php/sessions/sess_ri2g1n2du79rg4rosresdmm14e, O_RDWR) failed: Read-only file system (30) in /home/vagrant/code/getvideo/index.php on line 16

in /home/vagrant/code/getvideo/index.php on line 16
`session_start();`

`sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/php/sessions`

> chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/php/sessions': Read-only file system

Comment: `Read-only file system`. How will you write in a read-only-filesystem?

Comment: So how can I make writing? Because my project uses session_start and it doesn't fork with this error